# Issue using special characters in dynamic email FROM name in Salesforce marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We are generating dynamic sender names from a data extension that is uploaded with "repect double quotes as text qualifier". The import goes perfectly, all field values import correctly and in the proper columns.

Rep Name in data extension = "Howard Duchaîne, CFP"

Email from name recieved in my inbox = "=?UTF-8?Q?Howard_Ducha=C3=AEne@mx0g-00054e98.pphosted.com"

Please note that if I remove the ", CFP" from the sales rep name it works perfectly. Seems like SFMC is having characters issues when using special characters with a comma as a single value.

Anyone seen this before? Thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is not on SFMC end, but on the way the receiving client reads your email headers.  The comma creates an issue as I believe it is used as a form of delimiter inside of the header parsing, which is causing the crazy in your from name.

It seems that the value should be wrapped inside of double quotes to help prevent the parser from reading the comma as a delimiter. (yes I do see you have the DE set to "Respect Double Quotes as Text Qualifier" which is great, but I believe when extracted through Personalization String or AMPScript, it does not come in with those double quotes.)

To quote @Dalin in their [answer on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555563/how-to-format-an-email-from-header-that-contains-a-comma#answer-15606313): (please make sure to +1 their answer if you find it useful)

> To elaborate on the answer by @Fls'Zen, yes the proper method is to
> enclose the name in double-quotes.
>
> From a practical point of view there's no harm in wrapping all names
> in double-quotes, just be sure to escape a double-quote if it appears
> in the display name `\"` (or just replace with a single-quote). But if
> you want to be completely by the spec, you shouldn't use the double
> quotes if you don't have to.
>
> For all the dense details, E-mail header fields are defined by [RFC
> 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322). The relevant section for multiple originators in the From header is [3.6.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.2), and the relevant sections for quoting delimiters is [3.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.2.1)
> and [3.2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.2.4).

or this answer from @mikefrey [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35370571/how-to-add-a-comma-to-a-mailgun-from-field-for-outbound-emails):

> Wrap the name portion of the address in double quotes, like this:
>
> `from: '"Excited, User" <mailgun@sandbox-123.mailgun.org>',`
>
> Here's the site I'm using for reference:
> http://mailformat.dan.info/headers/from.html

Comment: Thanks @Gortington. I will peruse the info you shared and perform some additional testing on my end.

I did also try simply hard coding a default value at the data extension shell level wrapping the name in double quotes (which felt odd and hacky!), but it did technically work.  I only tested to an Outlook 2013, and when doing this method it had an extra space at the front when received in my inbox.

Not sure how I would translate this into my AMPscript which is used to populate the Sender Profile.

Comment: UPDATE: I added an INDEXOF part to my ampscript in my SFMC sender profile to apply quotes when a comma exists which fixes my issue for the names with commas and special characters, but breaks it for names with commas without special characters.

With that said, I only have one name presently in my data set which I could isolate by changing the search value from ","to a unique special character "î" which should work as an interim solution.